# C++ - Infinite ouput to console

Tags: c++, eclipse, runtime-error, eclipse-cdt

since I start to learn C++, I have a little problem either with IDE Eclipse CDT or with C++ itself.
Okey, more specifically...
This problem occurs when I stop program with the Terminate button.
What's happening? When I compile and run this couple of code:

```
int main(){
    char operace;
    short int stavba = 0;
    short int vstup;
    cout<<"Vítá vás kalkulačka pro pány teoretiky.";
    cout<<endl<<"Udejte výchozí matamatickou operaci pro celý číselný výraz:";
    cin>>operace;
    for(short int zadani = 0;vstup != 0;zadani++){
        cout<<"Vložte "<<zadani<<". číselný výraz:"<<endl;
        cin>>vstup;
        if(operace == '+'){
            stavba+= vstup;
        }
        else if(operace == '-'){
            stavba -= vstup;
        }
        else if(operace == '*'){
            stavba *= vstup;
        }
        else{
            stavba /= vstup;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Výsledek činí: "<<stavba;
    return 0;
}
```

... Output to the Eclipse console looks like this:

```
Vítá vás kalkulačka pro pány teoretiky.
Udejte výchozí matamatickou operaci pro celý číselný výraz:+
Vložte 0. číselný výraz:
5

Vložte 1. číselný výraz:
1
Vložte 2. číselný výraz:
0
Výsledek činí: 6
```

No issue - expected behaviour.
But now, when I terminate App through the Terminate button (when runtime is inside the for loop):

```
Vítá vás kalkulačka pro pány teoretiky.
Udejte výchozí matamatickou operaci pro celý číselný výraz:Vložte 0. číselný výraz:
Vložte 1. číselný výraz:
Vložte 2. číselný výraz:
Vložte 3. číselný výraz:
Vložte 4. číselný výraz:
Vložte 5. číselný výraz:
Vložte 6. číselný výraz:
...
```

Note that I **don't make any input**. In fact, program's **behaviour is normal** but I'm confused why occurs this "aesthetic error".

Could You explain me this? Thank You :-}.

Comment: Some cultural neutrality, please. There are worse questions without down-votes (even with up-votes) in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error: 'vstup' is not initialized, but it is set inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your first help :-}. Even though this don't fix the error, you explain me another error - syntax error - very vell :-}.